# Deriving Van der Waerden's theorem from Rado's theorem

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

In Ramsey Theory Van der Waerden theorem states that,

> Let $k,r$ be positive integers. Then in every partitioning of the
>   positive integers into $r$ classes there is one class which contains
>   an arithmetic progression of length $k$.

This was proved by Van der Waerden in 1927.

Rado's theorem proved in 1933 states:

> Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} \vec{c_1}&\vec{c_2}&\cdots \vec{c_n} \end{pmatrix}$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with integer entries and $r$
>   be a positive integer. Call the system of linear equations $Ax=0$
>   $r$-regular if every partitioning of the natural numbers into $r$
>   classes is such that one of classes contains a solution of this
>   system. Call this system regular if it is $r$-regular for all $r\ge
> > 1$. Then $Ax=0$ is regular if and only if there exists a positive
>   integer $k$ and a partition $C_1,C_2,\cdots,C_k$ of the column vectors
>   of $A$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{\vec{c_i}\in C_1}\vec{c_i}=0$ and
>   for all $j>1$ the vector $\displaystyle\sum_{\vec{c_i}\in
> > C_j}\vec{c_i}$ is a rational linear combination of the column vectors
>   from $C_1,\cdots,C_{j-1}$.

My question is, is it possible to derive Van der Waerden's theorem from Rado's theorem by choosing an appropriate $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&      &      &&1\\
 &1 &-1    &      &&1\\
 &  &1     &-1    &&1\\
 &  &      &\ddots\\
 &  &      &1     &-1    &1
\end{pmatrix}_{(k-1)\times(k+1)}$